# D3 selection - reflecting data changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a newbie in D3, so sorry for a naive question...

Reading https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join I see that to apply every data (already joined to a selection) change to the selection I need to repeat the data joining (i.e. `.data(...)`, `join(...)`) and all necessary functions for new attributes/styles/ etc. calculation (i.e. `.attr(...)`, `text(...)`) after every data change?

**Is it really so or I'm missing something?**

I was naively hoping that it's enough to join the data to a selection and describe the join behavior once - and then the selection should automatically reflect to the data changes...

This is my simple experiment on https://wattenberger.com/blog/d3#manipulating-the-dom which proves my assumption (in the red rectangle - there is the annoying repetition I'm asking about):
[image: (without the marked part of code that doesn't work)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it really so or I'm missing something?

Yes, it is. The reason is quite simple: D3's `data()` method binds the datum to each element. If you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/f8c53bf94712f734f6fce2449e136c12c3d3c5d7/src/selection/data.js#L62), this is the most important line regarding your question:

```
node.__data__ = data[i];
```

As you can see, each datum in the data array is bound as a `__data__` property (attention: do not play with that property, that's just D3 internals, if you need to access the datum do it as we usually do).

And that's specially true in your case, since you have an array of **primitives** (numbers). Changing the data array from:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

...to:

```
let array = [42, 200, 0, 17, 22];
```

... will have no magical effect in the bound data (let alone the element itself).

The only situation where a change in the data array is translated to the bound datum is when you have *objects* as the datum for the elements, since the bound `__data__` property is just a reference to those objects. Have a look at this example:

```js
const data = [{
  name: "foo"
}, {
  name: "bar"
}];

const divs = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .join("div")
  .html(d => d.name);

setTimeout(() => {
  data[1].name = "foobaz";
  divs.html(d => d.name);
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerardo! Your explanation is clear.

I'd like to make a couple of notes.

1) Even though in your example every element is bound to a non-primitive value, you still need to repeat `.html(d => d.name)`.

So there is no even non-magical effect :)


2) If you modify `data` set, you will need also to repeat more stuff:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        data.push({ name: "newEntry" });

        d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
          .data(data)
          .join("div")
          .html(d => d.name);
      }, 1500);
```

A `selecetion` could be smarter... :(

Comment: What I mean saying "A selecetion could be smarter...":

Since I described which data to join, which elements to produce and how to use every data piece - it would be great, if D3 remembers all that and apply to every existing and new matching element on every bound data change...

Comment: Yes, you still need to repeat everything: D3 doesn't change anything magically, unless you explicitly ask it to do so. And that's a good thing, actually.

Comment: I consider what I described in my previous comment an "explicit ask": I ask D3 to make a selection by the provided selector and provide a complete description of what to do with the selection (particularly - how to represent every necessary piece of data in DOM). I consider a D3's amnesia :) that I need to repeat that explanation to D3 on every data change.
I hope you understand what I'm about.
Well, nowadays likely it's better to not use D3 as a direct DOM manipulator - but to use something like React (and leverage D3 only for its great data manipulation features)...
Thank you, Gerardo.